# Couchdb view generation performance

Tags: couchdb

How to avoid slow requests on frequently updated view in couchdb , when returned "up-to-date"  is not important, what I am talking is probably caching  , and wondering is there any out of the box solution without involving third party software like "nginx cache" 
What I've tried is set compression to 0,
`[{db_fragmentation, "0%"}, {view_fragmentation, "0%"}]` yet the views sometimes take 30+ seconds to be available for the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding  `&update=false` on the end of url seems to do the job

I am "relaxed" again